# c++ template for rapidjson::Value

Tags: c++, templates, rapidjson

I try to create template to function for set data to array. I make it like this:

```
template <class T1>
        void SetArray(rapidjson::Document &JsonObj, std::string ArrayName, T1 value)
        {
            if (!JsonObj.IsObject())
                JsonObj.SetObject();


            rapidjson::Document::AllocatorType& alloc = JsonObj.GetAllocator();

            rapidjson::Value KeyPart;
            KeyPart.SetString(ArrayName.c_str(), alloc);

            rapidjson::Value ValuePart;
            ValuePart.SetString(value.c_str(), alloc);
}
```

I cant find how to different value type (std::string, int, bool etc.) by T1
Please help, thanks!

Comment: The usual way would be to not use a template for SetArray, just regular overloaded functions. Sometimes SetArray can be a template that shares most of the implementation but hands off to regular overloaded functions for the parts that are specific to each type.

Answer (score 0):

The `rapidjson::Value` constructor already has overloads for the various types, so you should just do

```
rapidjson::Value ValuePart{value};
```

and let the compiler figure it out.